# Databricks Python Optimization

Tags: sql, optimization, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I need your help please, i have a simple code in python which lists all the fields in the tables in all the databases that are on databricks, there are a little nearly 90 tables and I would like to save the result in a txt or csv file. here is the code used it works but it takes 8 hours to finish it is too long how can I optimize or have another way for it to be faster?

```py
# table containing all name of database in databricks  
#df_tables = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM bd_xyh_name")
#DynoSQL is a string table for result in txt

def discribe():
  try: 
     for i in df_tables.collect():
        showTables="""show tables in {};""".format(i.nombd)
        df1=spark.sql(showTables)
        for j in df1.collect():
            describeTable="""describe table {0}.{1};""".format(j.database,j.tableName)
            df2=spark.sql(describeTable)
            #df3=df2.collect()
            df3 = df2.rdd.toLocalIterator()
            for k in df3:
              #df=df2.select(df2.col_name;k.data_type)
              #spark.sql("insert into NewTable VALUES ("+j.database+";"+j.tableName+";"+k.col_name+";"+k.data_type+");")
              spark.sql("insert into DynoSQL select \""+j.database+";"+j.tableName+";"+k.col_name+";"+k.data_type+"\"")
             # request="insert into NewTable VALUES ({};{};{};{});""".format(j.database,j.tableName,k.col_name,k.data_type)
              #spark.sql(request)
             
  except:
    raise
```

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting here. It won't get you help any faster, and text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand. It's also rather impolite to SHOUT at us when you're asking us for free help to solve your problem. Thanks.

Comment: If you take out the `spark.sql("insert into DynoSQL select` how long does it take? Step one of troubleshooting is breaking the problem into pieces and working out which piece is the problem.m Also... how many records are in your resulting CSV? How many tables and databases?

Comment: @KenWhite i dont know what are you talking about i I did not shout at all I am polite and courteous, I ask for help yes, so if you can help it is with joy otherwise no need to say that it is free I already know thank you

Comment: Your entire title was in ALL CAPS, which I edited out. You can view the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70614632/revisions) to see it if you don't remember what you typed.

Comment: yes but title in CAPS does not necessarily mean that I scream, in the emails you do the same for the titles so I do not see why you interpret things like that but thank you anyway

Comment: Maybe I'm in a completely different generation or something, but onlinre caps 100% = shouting

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below logic .

**Logic** :

- Get the available databases within workspace and make `list`
- Iterate the databases name and get the available tables within databases and write into temp table. (Temp table you should create as managed one)

**Advantage** : Based on this logic , at a time only one databases only will be processed and if fails during the process , we can start from failing `databases` instead of whole workspace level.

**Code Snippet** :

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat, lit

df = spark.sql("show databases")
list = [x["databaseName"] for x in df.collect()]

for x in list:
    df = spark.sql(f"use {x}")
    df1 = spark.sql("show tables")
    df_loc.write.insertInto("writeintotable")
display(df1)
```

Screenshot :

[image]

Comment: thx you for your answer but this will just list me the tables , I want to see in each table the columns and their type

Comment: thanks for ack. Yes Ali, I did't give complete code here . Just given a logic here . what i meant here , first listed out all databases based on above code and iterate all databases in that loop and get the required all information through that iterations . Please let me know if you need more info .